# Restore Database with Multiple Restore commands

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

For automation, I have to dynamically construct the restore commands and thus I have created a script. A `.bak` file is created on a remote server and I receive it daily. The script builds the restore string and executes it.

Only hindrance so far is I'm unable to restore the db on multiple steps, because the back up file comes from an external source and fails with  "Directory lookup for the file "xxxxxx.ndf" failed with the operating system error 3 (The system cannot find the path specified.)." It is the folder where the backup resides on the remote server.

Basically the script looks like:

```
RESTORE DATABASE x FROM DISK = 'E:x.bak'  WITH MOVE 'a' TO 'E:\x.mdf', NORECOVERY    
RESTORE DATABASE x FROM DISK = 'E:x.bak'  WITH MOVE 'b' TO 'E:\x1.ndf', NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG x      FROM DISK = 'E:\x.bak' WITH MOVE 'c_log' TO 'E:\x.ldf',NORECOVERY
RESTORE DATABASE x WITH RECOVERY
```

How can I achieve such a scenario?

Comment: Does the server you're restoring to have an E: drive?

Comment: Yes. I was just wondering if the above statements would be valid together for a restore operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will restore the database to the desired location:

```
RESTORE DATABASE x
FROM DISK = 'Filepathofbackupfile.bak'
WITH RECOVERY,
MOVE 'logicalDatafilename' TO 'Newfilepath.mdf',
MOVE 'logicalLogfilename' TO 'Newfilepath.ldf'
```

Comment: I know this one. I was just trying to find out if it was possible with the way I wrote.. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are able to restore a database with `NORECOVERY` and then perform more restore produces within one script, allowing you to recover a database to a point in time.

When you restore full and differential backups you should have a `MOVE` statement for both the data *and* logs.

I would recommend moving the backups you want to restore to a directory which know you have access to (something local to server will limit network traffic as well).

Also, it's worth checking that the file extensions match what you've specified in your script. (The default extension for a Transaction Log backup tends to be .trn)

I hope this helps you.